# How to find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them ? with answer

Tags: python, list, duplicates

My own Solution:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,8,8,8]
counter=0
for j in list(set(list1)):
    for i in list1:
        if j==i:
            counter=counter+1
    print(j,"have",counter,"duplicates")
    counter=0
```

give some suggestion

Comment: Okay... what's your question? What's not working right now?

Comment: You could just use `collections.Counter()`.

Comment: You said you want to create another list with the counts. Why are you just printing the counts instead of putting them in a list?

Comment: `list2.append((j, counter))`

Comment: I recommend putting `counter=0` at the beginning of the loop instead of the end. Then you don't have to write it twice.

Comment: thanks barmar for all suggestions, yes I will modify the code as you suggested.

Comment: @Barmar All your comments are just a couple minutes apart; I noticed that on a sizable handful of questions. I recommend to combine related ideas into one comment, and use the edit feature when possible to make additions. This is helpful for askers and reviewers.

Comment: @IOTRnD It sounds like you do not need help because you already began with a solution — or else you have not specified an actual problem to be solved. I recommend to post your own solution separately as an answer, not in the question itself, per [this help page/guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Andrew,thank you for the suggestion. Actually I have mentioned half cooked solution with some mistake (repetitions).But , yes I will try to  add the answer next time separately. Have a good day!

Comment: @AndrewF If the comments are unrelated thoughts, I tend to make them separate rather than try to cram them all into a single comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,8,8,8]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [(i, count) for i, count in Counter(list1).items() if count > 1]
[(4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 2), (8, 4)]
```